# How to Revert in-built Dataset in R?

Tags: r

How do I revert an in-built dataset in R? I happened to transform it, but want to use the original datset now.

Comment: `rm(in-built-dataset)` should make the original version available again.

Comment: @akrun Is it? I am new to this forum. I thought an upvote does it. Is that how I can accept answers?

Comment: @Swarnalakshmi, look for the ckeckmark next to an answer waiting to be filled.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Hey I just see an up-vote sign and a flag sign. There is no checkmark.

Comment: @akrun I know what you are talking about, but the only options available to me are and upvote and a flag. No downvote and no tick mark sign. Its very strange. :/

Comment: @Swarnalakshmi  I guess you figured it out:-)

Comment: Its awkward,, I can see for few questons but not for all. I cnt see for this one

Comment: @Swarnalakshmi  It is because nobody posted a solution here :-) .  Let me try by posting a solution and then check if that works :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `mtcars` is the dataset that got transformed, calling `data(mtcars)` again will get the original dataset. ie.

```
mtcars <- mtcars[,2:3]
ncol(mtcars)
#[1] 2
data(mtcars)
ncol(mtcars)
#[1] 11
```